# Rezise Azure Linux VM - redhat

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-linux

I have a Linux (redhat 7.6) VM and I need to give more RAM.

actually size: standard A1_v2 (2gb RAM)

new size: A4_v2 (8gb RAM)

If I do the resize by Azure portal, is there any considerations? Or any linux configuration that I will lose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your vm would be rebooted to perform the resize. nothing on the OS level changes (well, unless you have some changes in memory, that would not be preserved after a reboot). basically if your vm (and\or applications inside the vm) can handle the reboot - nothing will break.